# XSLT remove nodes within nodes of the same name

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I've got an XML document.

It's got loads of `para` nodes inside other `para` nodes.

I want to remove the ones inside and keep the inner text joining it to the other `para` nodes inner text.

**Example XML**

```
<document>
<head>
<front>The front page</front>
</head>
<h1>
<para id="1234">This is the inner text <para> it needs joining together</para> maybe with other text</para>
</h1>
</document>
```

**Desired output**

```
<document>
<head>
<front>The front page</front>
</head>
<h1>
<para id='1234'>This is the inner text it needs joining together maybe with other text</para>
</h1>
</document>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para/para">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it is a rather trivial problem. Why do you think this statement is about you?

Comment: You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBd

Comment: Thanks for your help!